# Hibernate Envers: get revision for the newly created entity item

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have an audited Entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class MyEntity {
  ...
}
```

And a creation method in service layer:

```
@Transactional
public MyDto createMyEntity() {
  MyEntity newEntity = new MyEntity();
  newEntity = repository.save(newEntity);

  // {1}

  return toDto(newEntity); // {2}
}
```

{2} maps existing `MyEntity` fields to the corresponding `MyDto` fields.

The `MyDto` consists of the same fields as `MyEntity` and, additionally, the `revisionNumber`:

```
public class MyDto {
  ...
  private int revisionNumber;
  // getters and setters
  ...
}
```

My goal is to return from `createMyEntity()` a `MyDto` with the valid `revisionNumber` but I could not retrieve this information at the step {1} because the new `MyEntity` is not actually created in the database.

This issue might even not be related to Envers rather to Hibernate transactions in general..

Answer (score 2):

The issue you face is one that is related to the fact that Envers flushes it's audit action queue in the transaction's before-completion callback, which happens just before the commit occurs.

You have a few options.

- Restructure your code so that you construct the DTO after the transaction commit, allowing you to query the Envers audit history tables for the revision number you need.
- Use Spring's `TransactionSynchronizationManager` to register a synchronization callback for `afterCommit` where you perform the Envers audit history table query and inject the revision number in your partially constructed DTO.
- Use Spring's newer `@TransactionEventListener` approach where you can essentially do the same `afterCommit` logic but in a cleaner way that is considered *decoupled*.